# Pi Hole Local DNS Not Working

Tags: pi-hole

My routers DHCP is set up to use pihole as the default DNS for clients on my network. I am trying to access local web services using the local DNS feature in pihole. The hostnames seems to resolve fine when executing a dig or nslookup command but doesn't resolve properly in a browser. Any idea what is going on here? Having the same problem on every device connected to the network.
[image: Chrome Lookup]

[image: Dig Command]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of error messages.  They are inaccessible to browsers for the blind.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being a date time issue on the pihole device. After manually synchronizing it I was able to access local dns records via browser again.